# increase quality/clarity/brightness of the photos taken with android camera

Tags: android, photo

I have an android app where I'm using the android camera in order to take photos.And after struglling a little bit I managed to have my picture where I want and how I want.The final problem is the quality of the image.

When my preview starts everything looks very clear and great but after taking the photo and showing the final result the image is not looking good at all.

Here is how my `surfaceChanged()` method looks like-where I'm setting some parameters:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
        if (mPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPictureSizes();

 System.out.println("Lista de parametrii este urmatoarea:"+sizes);
       Size   size = sizes.get(7);
      p.setPictureSize(size.width,size.height);
       mCamera.setParameters(p);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = true;
    }
```

Coudl someone tell what's the way to increase the quality of my photo.Thanks!

EDIT:

In `activity A` where the picture is taken I use a bundle to send the image to another `activity B` where I store it on the `SDCARD`.Here is how I do it:

`Activity A`:

```
 Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback(){
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

            if (imageData != null) {

                Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putByteArray("imageData", imageData);
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext,ImageDisplayActivity.class);
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);

                setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
                finish();

            }
        }
    };
```

in `activity B`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 5;
        byte[] imageData = extras.getByteArray("imageData");
        Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData , 0, imageData.length,options);

       Matrix mat=new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(90);
        bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImage, 0, 0,  myImage.getWidth(),myImage.getHeight(), mat, true); 

        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmapResult);
        drawTextImage(bitmapResult);
```

I receive the picture I put it in a bitmap, I rotate it and draw a text on it in the method `drawTextImage()` .
After all this I store the `bitmapResult` on `sdcard` using this:

```
  public static boolean StoreByteImage(Context mContext, Bitmap bitmap, int quality, String expName) {


        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        String extStorageDirectory=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + newFolder);
        if(myNewFolder.mkdirs())
        {
        myNewFolder.mkdir();
        }
        try {     

            //fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory.toString() +"/image.jpg");
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myNewFolder +"/"+expName+".jpg");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bos);

            bos.flush();
            bos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I ussually call it like this: `StoreByteImage(getBaseContext(),bitmapResult,100,String.valueOf(value));`
Thanks

Comment: But it's looking disaster.There must be something because when I take a photo with the camera, outside the application...just for fun, the picture is looking gorgeous!

Comment: I hope I'll find the solution cause otherwise....I don't know what I'm going to do!

Comment: What specifically do you mean by quality? Resolution? Clarity? Brightness? Contrast? Color balance? There are many things that account for the quality of a photo.

Comment: Clarity/brightness....my image looks blurred right now

Comment: The Android camera software is probably accounting for the motion of the phone when snapping the picture.  I suspect that the blurriness in your software photos is because of the phone moving when you press the camera button.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because auto-focus was disabled.

Try adding this permission to your Android Manifest:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: I also have same problem but still not getting the proper result.